# Supabase RLS shenanigans (I'm trying to implement an RLS policy to one of my Supabase tables & the policy is automatically changing to something else)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to implement an RLS policy to one of my Supabase tables and the policy is automatically changing to something else.

I have a table called "Employees" which stores user data including a column called role, which is used to control the access of the users. There are 3 roles user/superuser/admin.

I want to implement a policy that checks the current users uuid and see if they are admin, if so then grant them all access.

I've written the following policy for this.

```
(( SELECT "Employees".role
   FROM "Employees"
  WHERE ("Employees".id = auth.uid())) = 'admin'::text)
```

and when I save this policy it automatically changes to the following

```
(( SELECT "Employees_1".role
   FROM "Employees" "Employees_1"
  WHERE ("Employees_1".id = auth.uid())) = 'admin'::text)
```

So, it somehow adds the name of "Employees_1" table which I have not created.

I've used this same policy on another one of my table "Customers" and it works fine there.

Comment: It’s just aliasing your table - presumably to avoid a clash with another instance of the table. As it’s just an alias, why do you care?

Comment: The "Employees_1" type of syntax throws a javascript error for infinite loop, and also I was curious why it was doing the change especially because it worked on other tables. So, I guess we cannot reference the table we are writing the RLS policy of without an alias. 

But thanks for letting me know it's an alias, I'm new to supabase so I didn't see that.